# Postgres10 - CREATE TABLE AS with partition

Tags: django, postgresql, database-partitioning

I have an existing Postgres9 table, where every time I make a query, the WHERE clause includes the id of the US state. I would love to use Postgres10 [Declarative Partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) to make a new version of this table, but with a LIST partition based off of the 50 states.

I am trying things like:

```
CREATE TABLE partitioned_stuff AS TABLE stuff PARTITION BY LIST( state );
```

but this gives `syntax error at or near "PARTITION"`

Do I have to recreate the `stuff` table schema manually?

Comment: My guess are you need to alter your parent table with partition.. And after that you make table partition.. And remove `AS TABLE stuff`..

Comment: You mean to make [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=707e6d898e8b06ab86b41f5d3f28aeb2)?

Comment: @dwir182 from the Postgres docs on declarative partitions: `It is not possible to turn a regular table into a partitioned table or vice versa. However, it is possible to add a regular or partitioned table containing data as a partition of a partitioned table, or remove a partition from a partitioned table turning it into a standalone table; see ALTER TABLE to learn more about the ATTACH PARTITION and DETACH PARTITION sub-commands.`

Comment: therefore I am not able to merely alter the parent table. Nor did I want to create the table manually, as in that fiddle. However, I ended up doing just that, because I could not find a better way

Comment: Still you need to alter.. From documentation use `ALTER TABLE` to attach partition.. You should give more elaborate info about limitation you face..